# Alter shared mdToolbar from view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I have a SPA in [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) which is displaying an [`mdToolbar`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar) element with a hamburger menu + left sidenav. That menu at the moment resides in my index.html where I have also set-up a `<ui-view>` element to render the view.

Now I have a view with a [`mdList`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/list) in it. When the user selects some items, I want a delete icon to appear in the toolbar. That delete icon should be linked to the delete action of my controller which is of course specific to the view loaded, not to index.html.

I want to know what a recommended pattern for this would be. I can think of some ways to do it, but those are ugly. I was thinking in the direction of being able to have some placeholder area in the toolbar which I can replace with contents from my view, where the element actions (`ngClick`) are linked to the actions of the view controller. Does anyone know a good tutorial or codepen-like example of how to do this?

**Update**

I've now got something implemented that I'm happy with, but it's not quite there yet. What I did is create a `menuService` which is injected in the controller behind my menu (it's not a separate view, could be but doesn't make a difference in this scenario). The menu controller binds to this service and other services can inject stuff in it. In my test scenario, I inject a string which is then displayed in the toolbar, all ok.

The only thing I now need to do is instead of a string, inject a button with an event handler which goes back to the controller of the view. I'm not quite certain how to do that yet.

**Another update**

So I created this class:

```
export class CommandButton {
    svgSrc: string;
    click: () => void;
}
```

which I can inject into my menuService and then binds to the menu controller. Works fine for the icon (the button appears) but as one might expect (I did), the click function doesn't work. I set this in the view controller as follows:

```
var deleteButton = new Services.CommandButton();
deleteButton.svgSrc = 'icons/ic_delete_24px.svg';
deleteButton.click = this.deleteLogs;
this.menuService.setButtons([deleteButton]);
```

And the code for this.deleteLogs is simply:

```
deleteLogs() {
    console.log('deleting logs');
}
```

Code for the buttons:

```
<div ng-repeat="button in ctrl.buttons">
    <md-button ng-click="button.click">
         <md-icon md-svg-src="{{button.svgSrc}}" class="md-icon md-24"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
</div>
```

What I hoped for is that this would trigger the deleteLogs method in the view controller, but that's not the case. I need data from the view as that is where the items are selected. As far as I can see there's just nothing happening so the binding fails somewhere. What would be a good way to make sure the click event makes to to the view controller function? I could do a $rootscope.$broadcast but that feels hacky.

**Last update**

Never mind, I found my own bug. The binding of the event was incorrect, should have been (note the parenthesis):

```
<md-button ng-click="button.click()">
```

Comment: Did you know you can create multiple [`ui-view`s on the page and give them names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)? You can have one main `ui-view` and another named-one inside the `mdToolbar` where you can load current view-specific buttons.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for the tip, going to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've figured out a nice way to do this. The post itself now also contains the answer.